# How to replace right side values based on a character in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a ComputerNo column for Student Table. A special character 'C' exist in every cell. i need to replace all characters after C. Ex. 278287C100  --> 278287C. Total 300000+ data in my table. please help me out with an update query. Thanks in advance.

```
278287C0
1671755C1
1671841C2
1671810C3
1671779C4
160771C5
256050C6
275222C7
1625345C8
1617362C9
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk Replace in SQL-Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877521/bulk-replace-in-sql-server)

Comment: @sebu : What should be result if data like '1254C525C54'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try something like this (make test - and use transaction - before apply results in production env):

```
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = SUBSTRING(  FIELD, 1, CHARINDEX('C', FIELD));
```

Comment: Thanks !  Please consider my question as a helpful question .

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please try the following code

```
 Update your_table set your_column=SUBSTRING(your_column,1,CHARINDEX('C',your_column))
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Use below Update Statement:

```
UPDATE Student SET 
ComputerNo= CASE ISNULL(ComputerNo,'') 
            WHEN '' THEN ComputerNo
            ELSE LEFT(ComputerNo,LEN(ComputerNo) - CHARINDEX('C',REVERSE(ComputerNo)) + 1)
            END
```

Comment: Thanks !  Please consider my question as a helpful question .

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `LEFT` function

```
 UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = LEFT(FIELD,CHARINDEX('C', FIELD));
```

Comment: Thanks !  Please consider my question as a helpful question .

Comment: Yes 
SELECT LEFT('278287C0',CHARINDEX('C', '278287C0'));  Reslt OK, Thanks